# How to subdivide new Hair System curves for UE5 export?

Tags: bezier-curves, hair, resolution

When I'm exporting it to Unreal it appears very low res, cause it doesn't respect Blender's viewport SubD settings, obviously. Is there a way or a node to increase points?
[image]

Comment: Not sure if this helps but have you tried a Geometry Nodes modifier with a *Resample Curve* node?

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that worked, but turned out the real problem is in Child curves, not Parent guides. No matter how DENSE guides are, childs are ALWAYS same low res and I cannot find a way to crank them up...

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

1. Convert the curve hair to the particle one, which you can find when shifting your curve hair into sculpt mode:
   [image: convert the curve hair]
2. Increase the path steps on the particle system penal until it looks smooth enough:
   [image]
3. Export it to UE5 as Alembic

Comment: It would be nice to detail in your answer how to convert curve hairs to particles hairs.

Comment: @L0Lock  you are right haha : )